# Stash Playa field from Matrix (context)

Tags: matrix, playa, stash

I'm trying to Stash and output an entry from a channel.
Since I also need a dynamic=no menu on the left, I've been able to use a match of the {segment_2} against the url-title to dinamically display the actual entry.

I would like to display, under the main content, its related entries, which are stored as matrix rows. Each related entry has a custom title, a custom bodycopy and a link to the actual entry. The link is stored in one of the Matrix fields as a Playa field. So far I've been able to achieve most of my requirements, but I can't seem to find a way to indicate the context in the get_list for the Playa.

Each related entry, lists links from other rows too. So, if I get 4 related results, each result lists its link and the ones from it's siblings (3+1) too.

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="patologie_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="elements_patologie" dynamic="no"}
    {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
    {stash:testo_patologia}{testo_patologia}{/stash:testo_patologia}
    {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
        {exp:stash:set_list:matrix name="matrix_link_patologia" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
            {matrix_link_patologia}
                {stash:titolo_link_patologia}{titolo_link_patologia}{/stash:titolo_link_patologia}
                {stash:testo_link_patologia}{testo_link_patologia}{/stash:testo_link_patologia}
                {exp:stash:set_list:playa parse_tags="yes" name="resources"}
                        {exp:playa:children col="link_patologia"}
                            {stash:link_patologia}{url_title}{/stash:link_patologia}
                        {/exp:playa:children}
                {/exp:stash:set_list:playa}
            {/matrix_link_patologia}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:matrix}            
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

<div class="page" id="patologie">
<div class="container">
    <aside class="aside-navigation">
        <nav class="side-menu">
            <ul>
                {exp:stash:get_list name="patologie_list"}
                <li><a href="{url_title}" class="active">{title}</a></li>
                {/exp:stash:get_list}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>

    <section class="main">
        <h1>Le patologie trattate</h1>
        {exp:stash:get_list name="patologie_list" match="#^{segment_2}$#" against="url_title"}
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {testo_patologia}

        <div class="related_entries">
            <ul>
                {exp:stash:get_list:matrix name="matrix_link_patologia" context="{entry_id}" limit="4"}
                <li>
                    <h3>{titolo_link_patologia}</h3>
                    <p>{testo_link_patologia} 
                        {exp:stash:get_list:playa name="resources"}
                        <a href="{link_patologia}">Continua</a></p>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:playa}
                </li>
                {/exp:stash:get_list:matrix}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using row_id and entry_id for the context. You might also need to increase the `parse_depth` on the outermost stash tag to `4`.

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="patologie_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="4"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="elements_patologie" dynamic="no"}
    {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
    {stash:testo_patologia}{testo_patologia}{/stash:testo_patologia}
    {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
        {exp:stash:set_list:matrix name="matrix_link_patologia" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
            {matrix_link_patologia}
                {stash:row_id}{row_id}{/stash:row_id}
                {stash:titolo_link_patologia}{titolo_link_patologia}{/stash:titolo_link_patologia}
                {stash:testo_link_patologia}{testo_link_patologia}{/stash:testo_link_patologia}
                {exp:stash:set_list:playa parse_tags="yes" name="resources" context="{row_id}-{entry_id}"}
                        {exp:playa:children col="link_patologia"}
                            {stash:link_patologia}{url_title}{/stash:link_patologia}
                        {/exp:playa:children}
                {/exp:stash:set_list:playa}
            {/matrix_link_patologia}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:matrix}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

<div class="page" id="patologie">
<div class="container">
    <aside class="aside-navigation">
        <nav class="side-menu">
            <ul>
                {exp:stash:get_list name="patologie_list"}
                <li><a href="{url_title}" class="active">{title}</a></li>
                {/exp:stash:get_list}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>

    <section class="main">
        <h1>Le patologie trattate</h1>
        {exp:stash:get_list name="patologie_list" match="#^{segment_2}$#" against="url_title"}
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {testo_patologia}

        <div class="related_entries">
            <ul>
                {exp:stash:get_list:matrix name="matrix_link_patologia" context="{entry_id}" limit="4"}
                <li>
                    <h3>{titolo_link_patologia}</h3>
                    <p>{testo_link_patologia} 
                        {exp:stash:get_list:playa name="resources" context="{row_id}-{entry_id}"}
                        <a href="{link_patologia}">Continua</a></p>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:playa}
                </li>
                {/exp:stash:get_list:matrix}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </section>
</div>
```

EDIT to add

If each row will only ever return a single related entry then there's no need to use set_list and get_list, and you can also do away with the Playa module tag and use the simpler field tag instead. Something like this:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="patologie_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="4"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="elements_patologie" dynamic="no"}
        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:testo_patologia}{testo_patologia}{/stash:testo_patologia}
        {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
            {exp:stash:set_list:matrix name="matrix_link_patologia" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
                {matrix_link_patologia}
                    {stash:row_id}{row_id}{/stash:row_id}
                    {stash:titolo_link_patologia}{titolo_link_patologia}{/stash:titolo_link_patologia}
                    {stash:testo_link_patologia}{testo_link_patologia}{/stash:testo_link_patologia}
                    {stash:link_patologia}
                        {link_patologia var_prefix="playa"} {!-- playa field inside matrix --}
                           {playa:url_title}
                        {/link_patologia}
                    {/stash:link_patologia}
                {/matrix_link_patologia}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:matrix}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

<div class="page" id="patologie">
<div class="container">
    <aside class="aside-navigation">
        <nav class="side-menu">
            <ul>
                {exp:stash:get_list name="patologie_list"}
                <li><a href="{url_title}" class="active">{title}</a></li>
                {/exp:stash:get_list}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>

    <section class="main">
        <h1>Le patologie trattate</h1>
        {exp:stash:get_list name="patologie_list" match="#^{segment_2}$#" against="url_title"}
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {testo_patologia}

            <div class="related_entries">
                <ul>
                    {exp:stash:get_list:matrix name="matrix_link_patologia" context="{entry_id}" limit="4"}
                    <li>
                        <h3>{titolo_link_patologia}</h3>
                        <p>{testo_link_patologia}
                            <a href="{link_patologia}">Continua</a></p>
                    </li>
                    {/exp:stash:get_list:matrix}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. Now I get 0 results.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to stash the row_id.
I still get 4 results though.

Comment: For debug purposes please check this file:
https://imgur.com/WmptVH1
I've added the {row_id} - {entry_id} to the links.

Comment: updated answer...

Comment: Thanks… Now I get just one link… but I'm debugging it's rendering… what's the purpose of that Playa prefix?

Comment: If you're using a variable that will conflict with the outer `channel:entries` tag, such as `{url_title}`, you'll need the prefix to distinguish between the parent and child entries.

Comment: Ok… but I get this:
http://i.imgur.com/u3mWa8e.png

Comment: it should be var_prefix="playa".
Thank you!